# Azure Function OpenAPI - Error same key has already been added

Tags: azure, azure-functions, openapi

I have a problem implementing OpenAPI in an Azure Function.

I am using the following package

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Expensions.OpenApi
```

This is the error:

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: result_list`1
```

The cause is because I have several functions that are returning the same type `CustomCollection<T>`

How could you implement a solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm hitting the same error, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Before inserting a data into a **custom generic collection** `(CustomCollection<T>)` try to ***remove/delete*** previous values or after got a values from function ***remove/delete*** the values in a `CustomCollection<T>`. This can helps to avoid conflict.
2. Try to use multiple `CustomCollection<T>` with different names can solve the problem.
3. Add a `key` value with some ***prefix*** or ***suffix*** characters while inserting.

Eg: Actual Key : `result_list` you can use as `result_list_fun1` or `fun1_result_list`